# Drawing on 4-bit indexed images in GDI+

Tags: windows, visual-c++, gdi+

I am trying to draw some basic graphics primitives(line, rectangle etc.) using GDI+ apis on 4-bit indexed bitmaps. I am using Bitmap() functions for creating the bitmap and loading the bitmaps.

```
Bitmap myBitmap(100/*width*/,100/*height*/,PixelFormat4bppIndexed/*Pixel format*/);
Graphics graphics(&myBitmap);
SolidBrush brush(Color(255,128,0,0));
graphics.FillRectangle(&brush,0,0,100,100);
```

But this doesn't work(No Rectangle created). 
What could be the problem? I tried manually using LockBits and modifying the bits manually, it works well, then why it doesn't work with Graphics gdi+ operations.

Comment: Shouldn't you first create the palette?

Comment: > But this doesn't work(No Rectangle created).Does not it throw an exception?

Comment: Don't ignore function return values.  You can't make this work, drawing into bitmaps that have an indexed color format is not supported.

Comment: When we create Bitmap object this way, it has by default palette selected. That palette we can get and check also. I create Pen object with having the same colors which are available in the palette of Bitmap object, but it didnt work, even it doesnt return any error. I tried this using DIB in GDI by creating 4 bit bitmap and setting the palette manually and then drawing using normal GDI functions. It was working smoothly.

Comment: And one more surprising thing is, when I try to get HBITMAP from a 4bppIndexed Bitmap, it returns a 32 bit HBITMAP(checked using GetObject) and if I lock bits of 4bppIndexed Bitmap and modify according to 4bpp, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve my problem. To perform gdi+ operations using Graphics object on 4 bit indexed bitmap, we need to perform following steps.

1. Create 4bpp HBITMAP directly or load image from file using LoadImage.
2. If loading from 4bpp file, then load palette from file in HPALETTE object.
3. Create desktop compatible dc.
4. Select and realize you palette in newly created dc.
5. select HBITMAP in your dc.
6. Create Graphics object using your dc.
7. Perform GDI+ operations on 4bpp indexed.

Though I didnt try with 8bpp but I think similar operations can be performed on 8bpp also.

Hope this help others also.